# Arduino Infrared not entering IF

Tags: c, arduino, infrared

I have an issue with my code, I have used Infrared Control in the past, but this time I'm 'nesting' it, so it could work like a menu. However I'm not entering the IF loop at line 84, can anybody see any issues? Thanks in advance.

http://pastebin.com/jNiL6m4X

Note that the exact same if loop is used at line 61 where it does work

Answer (score 0):

First, have you checked if at line 71, `resultCode` actually  is `BUTTON_CHMI`?
Otherwise you won't even enter the first switch-statement.

Second, from line 93 onwards, you have a `switch`-statement with several `CASE`-entries, and each of them lacks a `break`; hence, regardless of which `CASE'-statement applies, you may fall into`BUTTON_BACK`, where the exit condition is set to true; I suppose you will always exit the menu, regardless which button you press.